# flash antialiased systemfonts

Tags: flash, fonts, antialiasing

is there any way in flash to get text antialiased, which is rendered with a systemfont (without embedding any fonts into the swf)? if so - how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you display the text? TextField has an `antiAliasType` property
(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#antiAliasType).

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I did not notice.
But if you can afford to ask for Player 10, take a look at the new text engine: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/